# flutter app with firebase crashes on hot reload

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

Hey all I am having some problems with flutter and firebase after receiving a new update. If i try to hot reload the app then it will just crash. Below is the code that seems to be causing the problem and I also have the result of what happens when I run `flutter run --verbose`. Thanks for the help.

Code that seems to be causing the problem:

```
import 'package:CodingLog/model/dataSettings.dart';
import 'package:CodingLog/notifier/dataSettings_notifier.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';




getMainDataSettings(MainDataSettingsNotifier mainDataSettingsNotifier) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('mainDataSettings')
    .get();

  List<MainDataSettings> _mainDataSettingsList = [];

  snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
    MainDataSettings mainDataSettings = MainDataSettings.fromMap(document.data());
    _mainDataSettingsList.add(mainDataSettings);
  });

  mainDataSettingsNotifier.mainDataSettingsList = _mainDataSettingsList;
  print('getting data - 1');
}
```

Pubspec file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  charts_flutter: ^0.8.1

  image_picker: ^0.6.7+7

  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.3.8
  
  date_format: ^1.0.8

  flutter_swiper:
  
  intl: ^0.16.1

  flutter_statusbarcolor: ^0.2.3

  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2 

  provider: ^4.3.2+2


  uuid: ^2.2.2
```

This is the output of running `flutter run --verbose`:

```
[+35434 ms] Starting incremental build...
[   +2 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +1 ms] complete
[   +2 ms] Performing hot restart...
[  +12 ms] Scanned through 511 files in 6ms
[        ] Syncing files to device iPhone 8...
[        ] Scanning asset files
[   +1 ms] <- reset
[        ] Compiling dart to kernel with 2 updated files
[        ] <- recompile package:CodingLog/main.dart 7866d41d-8028-433a-9dfd-406bda335575
[        ] package:CodingLog/screens/data.dart
[        ] package:CodingLog/screens/feed.dart
[        ] <- 7866d41d-8028-433a-9dfd-406bda335575
[ +273 ms] Updating files
[ +405 ms] DevFS: Sync finished
[        ] Syncing files to device iPhone 8... (completed in 681ms)
[        ] Synced 29.0MB.
[        ] <- accept
[ +124 ms] Hot restart performed in 814ms.
[        ] Performing hot restart... (completed in 820ms)
[        ] Restarted application in 826ms.
[ +569 ms] Service protocol connection closed.
[   +1 ms] Lost connection to device.
[   +5 ms] DevFS: Deleting filesystem on the device
(file:///Users/masonhorder/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BB743712-8AB1-49E7-BB29-AC39EB2DE70E/data/Containers/Data/Application/066B0BC0-5C67-4DA7-A3DE-
713CCDC32E0E/tmp/CodingLogyN4gn4/CodingLog/)
[ +260 ms] Ignored error while cleaning up DevFS: TimeoutException after 0:00:00.250000: Future not completed
[   +7 ms] "flutter run" took 918,916ms.
[ +143 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 135ms
[   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +5 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error ?

Comment: do you mean by running, flutter run --verbose?

Comment: @SandeepChayapathi i added the results of the stacktrace

Comment: does this happen only on hot reload ? does a full rebuild solve it ?

Comment: @SandeepChayapathi a full rebuild works only if I am not running in release mode.

Comment: All I can say is, I have definitely seen this issue while integrating firebase core. There is one open issue https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3746 , adding your comments to this ticket might help the developer fix it.

Comment: Completely off topic, if you are looking for firebase alternative I'd look at https://rethinkdb.com/

Comment: @SandeepChayapathi ok thank you, i will look at both!